# Discord.py Logging deleted and edited messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots

I'm making a server bot for my server and I want to log all message deletions and edits. It will log into a log channel for staff to see. In the log channel, I want to have the message show what was deleted or what was before the message edit and what was after the edit of the message. How would I have to bot display the deleted or edited message?

```py
@client.event()
async def on_message_delete(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="{} deleted a message".format(member.name), description="", color="Blue")
    embed.add_field(name="What the message was goes here" ,value="", inline=True)
    channel=client.get_channel(channel_id)

    await channel.send(channel, embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [on_message_delete](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message_delete) and [on_message_edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message_edit) as you are using and then you should give the function message not ctx.

Example [on_message_delete](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message_delete):

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="{} deleted a message".format(message.member.name), 
    description="", color="Blue")
    embed.add_field(name= message.content ,value="This is the message that he has 
    deleted", 
    inline=True)
    channel=client.get_channel(channel_id)
await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Example [on_message_edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message_edit):

```
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(message_before, message_after):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="{} edited a 
    message".format(message_before.member.name), 
    description="", color="Blue")
    embed.add_field(name= message_before.content ,value="This is the message before 
    any edit", 
    inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name= message_after.content ,value="This is the message after the 
    edit", 
    inline=True)
    channel=client.get_channel(channel_id)
await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: This is so wrong. You have wrong syntaxes. While using `event` we don't use parentheses. Also to send message you don't use that command. It is `await channel.send(embed=embed)`

Comment: This was a long time ago so probably the versions have changed, what I am 100% sure about Is that you can 100% use parentheses on events.
and i am pretty sure that this was working back then, probably still working anyways

Comment: Nope. They don't. We get an error instead.

Comment: As I mentioned that was from some good time so it probably was working on the old version, hence why the guy marked it as correct and it got 3 upvotes, I will look to fix it for current versions anyways, ty for mentioning that for me

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav Did you really just comment after a year that this solution marked as "helpful and correct" is wrong? A lot happens in a year, new `discord.py` versions are released and then things can just change. Anyway: Nothing needs to be adjusted here, because at that time everything worked and was correct.

Comment: Thank you for saying that, just what I wanted to say.
@Dominik

Comment: Is there a method that I can mention the channel that the message has been deleted?

Comment: @RovinduThamuditha yes you can, you just do it like ```<#channelid>```.

Answer (score 1):

The way shown above will not work at the time of making this post. That's why I have edited it so that It will.

The line:

```
embed=discord.Embed(title="{} edited a 
    message".format(message_before.member.name), 
    description="", color="Blue")
```

It does not work as `message` does not have the attribute `member`. It also does not work because you can not set the colour to `Blue` or a string without integer conversion. The best way to do this is by just defining a hex like this enter `color=0xFF0000` this makes it red.

The full line changed:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="{} deleted a message".format(message.author.name),
                      description="", color=0xFF0000)
```

Here are the full two commands edited to work.

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="{} deleted a message".format(message.author.name),
                          description="", color=0xFF0000)
    embed.add_field(name=message.content, value="This is the message that he has deleted",
                    inline=True)
    channel = client.get_channel(channelid)
    await channel.send(channel, embed=embed)


@client.event
async def on_message_edit(message_before, message_after):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="{} edited a message".format(message_before.author.name),
                          description="", color=0xFF0000)
    embed.add_field(name=message_before.content, value="This is the message before any edit",
                    inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name=message_after.content, value="This is the message after the edit",
                    inline=True)
    channel = client.get_channel(channelid)
    await channel.send(channel, embed=embed)
```

I would at the top of your code define the channel you would like to use something like this.

```
logging_channel = channelID
# then at your two commands do this:
global logging_channel
```