# on_message_edit log embed not wanting to send

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get my bot to log in a channel when a message is edited. Whenever I edit a message, the bot will not log the embed below. My bot will also not send an error. My code is inside of a cog. How can I get this to work? Thanks

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_edit(self, before, after):
      embed=discord.Embed(title="Message Edited", color=0x00FFFF)
      embed.set_footer(text=f"Author ID:{before.author.id} • Message ID: {before.id}")
      embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
      embed.add_field(name='Before:', value=before.content + "\u200b", inline=False)
      embed.add_field(name="After:", value=after.content + "\u200b", inline=False)
      channel = self.bot.get_channel(845515189050409020)
      await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this post: [Logging deleted and edited messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63182846/discord-py-logging-deleted-and-edited-messages)?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code, I assume the `channel` you might be trying to get is returning as a `NoneType` object. You can find this with a quick `try/except`

Comment: @Dominik I forgot to load the cog file lmao.. works fine now

Answer (score 0):

According to this post: [Discord.py Logging deleted and edited messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63182846/discord-py-logging-deleted-and-edited-messages)

It should be the following:

```
@client.event()
    async def on_message_edit(self, before, after):
```

Comment: So I can't do this in a cog?

Comment: Also you cant have `self` in a event